# I can not understand how to screen the char ', and find it in the string

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to remove comments from a python code using a substring search algorithm in a string. But I ran into a problem. The code considers that the character ' is part of the comment, and therefore cuts everything further out, including the character itself.

When trying to debug, I saw that in contrast to the character ", which even in the line is transmitted as "\"", the character is ' transmitted as ''', which is a problem.
That is, if I try to screen this character, it simply does not find it.
If I try to replace the quotes responsible for the string with " "
That gives an error message that char and const char are incompatible.
But I didn't seem to use pointers anywhere.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string removeComments(string code)
{
    int n = code.length();
    string result;

    bool sin_comment = false;
    bool multi_comment = false;

    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if (sin_comment == true && code[i] == '\n')
            sin_comment = false;
        else if (multi_comment == true && code[i] == '\"' && code[i + 1] == '\"' && code[i+2] == '\"')
            multi_comment = false, i++; 
        else if (sin_comment || multi_comment)
            continue;
        else if ((code[i] != '\"' || code[i] != '\'') && code[i+1] == '#' && (code[i+2] != '\"' || code[i+2] != '\''))
            sin_comment = true, i++;
        else if (code[i] == '\"' && code[i + 1] == '\"' && code[i + 2] == '\"')
            multi_comment = true, i++;
        else  result += code[i];
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    string code;
    cout << "Enter your code: \n";
    getline(std::cin, code);
    cout << " Modified code: \n";
    cout << removeComments(code) << "\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

```
I enter the string: s += '# not "a comment' # comment
And I expect: s += '#not "a comment'
But I get: s +=
```

Comment: Your code will fail miserably if what is entered is less than 3 characters and starts with comments, as you access items out-of-bounds.  Second:  *That gives an error message that char and const char are incompatible.* -- what line gives this error message?

Comment: If a `#` within a string should not be treated as a comment indicator, shouldn't you have something to keep track of if you're in a string?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, The error is issued if in line 21 instead of  '\' 'use "'". Error appears on the operator !=.

Comment: Your multi-string detection is wrong. Consider characters """" (four double quotes). Your code will detect multi-string on first double quote, but it will detect end of multi-string on second double quote. Instead of detecting in advance (using i+1 and i+2) you must have a machine state (int quote_count; bool is_qouble_quote_string; bool in_multiline_string; bool in_singleline_string, bool escape_active) that counts the quotes and double quotes, and sets and resets the flags and counters accordingly on every new character. Pay attention to escape characters in single-line strings.